# Accurate Circular Orbit Equation in java

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics, gravity, orbital-mechanics

```
public void move(){
    double angle;

    for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++){
        if(Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ship.locX - (planets.get(i).locX + planets.get(i).radi), 2) + Math.pow(ship.locY - (planets.get(i).locY + planets.get(i).radi), 2))) < planets.get(i).gravrange){
            //Distance formula between spaceship and planets to determine whether the ship is within the influence of the planet.

            angle = ((Math.atan2((planets.get(i).locX + planets.get(i).radi) - ship.locX, (planets.get(i).locY + planets.get(i).radi) - ship.locY)) / Math.PI) + 1;
             //The problematic math equation.
```

Produces a double from 0 to 2, 0 being when ship.locY < planets.get(i).locY && ship.locX == (planets.get(i).locX - planets.get(i).radi). (when relative X = 0 and relative Y < 0.)

```
            if(ship.locX > (planets.get(i).locX + planets.get(i).radi)){xm += Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;}
            else{xm -= Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;}
            if(ship.locY > (planets.get(i).locY + planets.get(i).radi)){ym += Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;}
            else{ym -= Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;}                          
        }
    }
```

This uses the data to modify the X and Y velocities of the spacecraft.

This equation works for the majority of an orbit, but under certain circumstances has an issue in which the spacecraft undergoes a retrograde force, slowing it. Shortly afterward it begins to be repelled by the planetary body, which after a short period begins attracting it again. When the spacecraft reaches the original position at which this occurred, it begins to move in the opposite direction of its original orbit.

This continues to occur until the spacecraft begins a wavelike motion.

Is there a way to solve this, or am I simply using the wrong equation? I've been attempting to fix this for about two weeks now. I have no education in physics nor calculus at this point in time, so my understanding is limited.

Edit: The comments had questions about my math, so I'll attempt to answer them here. From what I know about atan2, it produces a number from -pi to pi. I divide by pi to produce a number from -1 to 1, then add 1 to produce 0 to 2. I then use this number as a radian measurement. My knowledge of radians (unit circle) is that a circle's radian measure is 0 to 2pi.

Edit 2: The following code has very different math but produces the desired results, save for issues of repelling rather than attracting when approaching the North and South 'poles' of the planet.

```
public void move(){
    double angle;
    double x1, x2, y1, y2;

    for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++){
        x1 = ship.locX;
        y1 = ship.locY;
        x2 = planets.get(i).locX + planets.get(i).radi;
        y2 = planets.get(i).locY + planets.get(i).radi;
        if(Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))) < planets.get(i).gravrange){
            //Distance formula between spaceship and planets
            angle = (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1); //Gets slope of line between points.

            if(angle > 0){
                if(y1 > y2){
                    xm += Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                    ym += Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                }else{
                    xm -= Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                    ym -= Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(y1 > y2){
                    xm -= Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                    ym -= Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                }else{
                    xm += Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;
                    ym += Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate;}
            }   
        }
    }
```

I wrote it up very quickly to see if using the slope of the line rather than that strange atan2 equation would help. Apparently it did. I also made the code a bit more readable in this section.

Comment: @asphere8--there's a very good chance that `atan` is causing you grief. I've struggled with it in a couple apps. Read carefully the Javadoc to make sure you're getting what you want. There are two `atan` methods: one with 2 arguments that you're using, one with just one. It might pay to switch. I'm going to try to find what my problem was and share it. It was awhile ago.

Comment: My frustration with `atan` was actually with the "argument" (trig angle) of complex numbers, but they're not far removed from positions in the plane. I wound up having to write my own function to do what I couldn't do with either version of `atan`. You might find [this article](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/arg_11.pdf)  inappropriate, given your mathematical self-description, but it describes the return results of typical `atan` functions. Note the fudging with pi and pi/2 in the text and especially in tables on pages 2 and 3.

Comment: Please note that I've jumped to a conclusion, but it's based on experience that is likely to vex others, too. I haven't studied your code. It could be that other aspects of the equations are screwed up. However since the code usually works, that's seems much more likely to be symptomatic of `atan` misuse than a fouled equation.

Comment: What's the `+1` at the end of the "problematic equation"?

Comment: Also, why divide by pi?

Comment: `atan` returns an angle that is measured in radians, but then you divide by pi to produce--what? But I see that you're doing the two operations I asked about to get something between 0 and 2, which you then pass to cos and sin. What's the significance of the interval from 0 to 2? I don't know the physics that should be involved, so maybe I'm missing something fundamental. That being said, I think I'm outta here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fixed my issue. I was overcomplicating my math equations as I usually do. Took me three weeks of Googling, asking people with degrees in physics and mathematics, and reading Javadocs before I figured that one out. Turns out how atan2 works is simply different from how I thought it worked and I was improperly using it.
The solution was simplifying the atan2 equation beforehand and removing the unnecessary additions.

```
        x1 = ship.locX;
        y1 = ship.locY;
        x2 = planets.get(i).locX + planets.get(i).radi;
        y2 = planets.get(i).locY + planets.get(i).radi;
        if(Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))) < planets.get(i).gravrange){
            //Distance formula between spaceship and planets

            angle = Math.atan2((y2 - y1),(x2 - x1)); //Converts the difference to polar coordinates and returns theta.

            xm -= Math.cos(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate; //Converts theta to X/Y
            ym -= Math.sin(angle) * planets.get(i).gravrate; //velocity values.
        }
```